# can't inject the values in the class from configuration created in gradle.properties

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, quarkus, quarkus-reactive

the question is i want to use "Mapping Configuration to objects" in quarkus i have a gradle.properties so i want to declare this array of objects in the .properties file
`myApplicationConfig.enabled = true` and i want to fetch and use this value we can do that by using @ConfigMapping(prefix = myApplicationConfig) as the annotation on top of the interface for mapping it my interface code:

```
    @ConfigMapping(prefix = "myApplicationConfig")
    @StaticInitSafe
    public interface ApplicationConfig {
        boolean enabled();
        List<Details> details();

          interface details{
            String name();
            int age();}
```

and after injecting into this `enabled()` i want to fetch it to other class there i want to do some operations such as printing the value so i've injected this interface there and trying to get the value but it says that

```
      ERROR [io.qua.run.boo.StartupActionImpl] (Quarkus Main Thread) Error running Quarkus: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.StartupActionImpl$1.run(StartupActionImpl.java:103)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:128)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:347)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:645)
    Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:66)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:41)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:120)
        at io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(Unknown Source)
        ... 6 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: io.smallrye.config.ConfigValidationException: Configuration validation failed:
        java.util.NoSuchElementException: SRCFG00014: The config property 
Config.enabled is required but it could not be found in any config source
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: io.smallrye.config.ConfigValidationException: Configuration validation failed:
    
        at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfigBuilder.build(SmallRyeConfigBuilder.java:453)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.generated.Config.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        ... 18 more
    Caused by: io.smallrye.config.ConfigValidationException: Configuration validation failed:
        java.util.NoSuchElementException: SRCFG00014: The config property Config.enabled is required but it could not be found in any config source
        at io.smallrye.config.ConfigMappingProvider.mapConfiguration(ConfigMappingProvider.java:805)
        at io.smallrye.config.ConfigMappingProvider.mapConfiguration(ConfigMappingProvider.java:761)
        at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfigBuilder.build(SmallRyeConfigBuilder.java:450)
        ... 19 more
    
    Caused by: io.smallrye.config.ConfigValidationException: Configuration validation failed:
    
    2022-10-21 11:47:11,847 INFO  [io.qua.dep.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain] (main) Attempting to start live reload endpoint to recover from previous Quarkus startup failure
    2022-10-21 11:47:11,900 INFO  [org.jbo.threads] (main) JBoss Threads version 3.4.2.Final
    2022-10-21 11:47:11,963 ERROR [io.qua.dep.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain] (main) Failed to start quarkus: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at io.quarkus.dev.appstate.ApplicationStateNotification.waitForApplicationStart(ApplicationStateNotification.java:51)
        at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.StartupActionImpl.runMainClass(StartupActionImpl.java:122)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.firstStart(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:146)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:480)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:67)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInCl(CuratedApplication.java:142)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInAugmentClassLoader(CuratedApplication.java:97)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.start(DevModeMain.java:132)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.main(DevModeMain.java:62)
        Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.quarkus.runtime.generated.Config
            at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
            at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
            at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.StartupActionImpl.runMainClass(StartupActionImpl.java:144)
            ... 7 more
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.StartupActionImpl$1.run(StartupActionImpl.java:103)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    
        at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:128)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:347)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:645)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:66)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:41)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:120)
        at io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(Unknown Source)
        ... 6 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: io.smallrye.config.ConfigValidationException: Configuration validation failed:
        java.util.NoSuchElementException: SRCFG00014: The config property Config.enabled is required but it could not be found in any config source
        at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfigBuilder.build(SmallRyeConfigBuilder.java:453)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.generated.Config.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        ... 18 more
    Caused by: io.smallrye.config.ConfigValidationException: Configuration validation failed:
        java.util.NoSuchElementException: SRCFG00014: The config property Config.enabled is required but it could not be found in any config source
        at io.smallrye.config.ConfigMappingProvider.mapConfiguration(ConfigMappingProvider.java:805)
        at io.smallrye.config.ConfigMappingProvider.mapConfiguration(ConfigMappingProvider.java:761)
        at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfigBuilder.build(SmallRyeConfigBuilder.java:450)
        ... 19 more
    
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: io.smallrye.config.ConfigValidationException: Configuration validation failed:
    
    Caused by: io.smallrye.config.ConfigValidationException: Configuration validation failed:
```

i'm unable to inject the data can anyone explain why i can't? or did i miss anything? or should i need to add these configs in build.gradle or somewhere else ? and also i want to declare an array of objects as

```
Config.details[0].name = "Sam"
Config.details[0].age = 12
Config.details[1].name = "Tim"
Config.details[1].age = "34"
```

but when i try to use them after injecting it throws empty list
please explain it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference#configuration-sources)

> **1. Config Sources By default, Quarkus reads configuration properties from multiple sources (by descending ordinal):**
>
> (400) System properties
>
> (300) Environment variables
>
> (295) .env file in the current working directory
>
> (260) Quarkus Application configuration file in
> $PWD/config/application.properties
>
> (250) Quarkus Application configuration file application.properties in
> classpath
>
> (100) MicroProfile Config configuration file
> META-INF/microprofile-config.properties in classpath
>
> The final configuration is the aggregation of the properties defined
> by all these sources. A configuration property lookup starts by the
> highest ordinal configuration source available and works it way down
> to other sources until a match is found. This means that any
> configuration property may override a value just by setting a
> different value in a higher ordinal config source. For example, a
> property configured using an environment property overrides the value
> provided using the application.properties file.

gradle is used to build the project not to provide by default any properties to `quarkus`.

So pick one of the above destinations and there add your configuration properties which will be picked then from `quarkus`

For example you can add

```
myApplicationConfig.enabled = true

myApplicationConfig.details[0].name = "Sam"
myApplicationConfig.details[0].age = 12
myApplicationConfig.details[1].name = "Tim"
myApplicationConfig.details[1].age = "34"
```

in the file `src/main/resources/application.properties`.